# Duda con input="file", subir el mismo archivo más de 1 vez

Tags: javascript, html, archivo, input

Tengo un proyecto en `React` pero en base a lo que voy a presentar aquí podre solucionar ese "problema" y lo pongo entre "" porque no es realmente un problema grande pero intento controlar todo lo que el usuario final podría intentar hacer.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden observar el **IconButton** con la carpeta si le doy click me abre la carpeta **downloads** que es donde tengo archivos `.xlsx` lo subo.

Dentro del IconButton tengo un codigo como el siguiente:

```js
const iptExcell = document.getElementById('excel-input')
let contador = 0

  iptExcell.addEventListener('change', e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      contador += 1
      console.log(e)
      console.log(`Hola ${contador}`)
  })
```

```html
<input title="ipt"  id='excel-input' accept=".xlsx, .csv" type="file"/>
```

El código exactamente no es así ya que es React (JSX)  y no Js Vanilla pero al final de cuentas tienen la misma función que es subir un archivo Excel....

El inconveniente y que quisiera solucionar si se puede es que yo subo un archivo Excel y con los datos que están adentro me hace una consulta a un servicio por medio de `axios` y los datos que recibe los renderizo en una tabla (Eso para dar contexto), pero si quisiera subir el mismo Excel con los mismos datos no lo hace a no ser que agarre un Excel con datos diferentes ahí si hace una nueva consulta.

Pueden hacer la prueba con el código que puse, escojan un archivo Excel y verán en la consola que muestra el ***"hola"*** pero si intentan de nuevo subir el mismo Excel no muestra de nuevo el ***"hola"*** o sea que no llega nada pero si agarran otro Excel cualquiera si lo vuelve a hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El evento `change` solo se ejecuta cuando el valor que recibe ha cambiado, es por eso que cuando envías el mismo archivo, el valor va a ser el mismo, por la cual no vuelve a ejecutar el evento. La solución sería asignar a vacío al valor, así, el `change` identifica que el valor va a ser diferente a vacío cada vez que se ingrese al listener, y el código se vuelve a ejecutar:

```js
const iptExcell = document.getElementById('excel-input')
let contador = 0

iptExcell.addEventListener('change', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  contador += 1
  console.log(e) // aquí leo el valor
  console.log(`Hola ${contador}`)
  iptExcell.value = '' // y luego lo pongo vacío
})
```

```html
<input title="ipt" id='excel-input' accept=".xlsx, .csv" type="file"/>
```

Comment: Ha caray que sencillo era pero bueno no lo sabía, muchas gracias @Cris223511.dev, ya lo arregle.